# set azure devops pipeline version control tag from task

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, versioning, azure-pipelines-build-task

Version tag is parsed from a file in an azure devops pipeline task but needs to be utilized at the end of the agent pipeline to set the version control tag.

I cannot seem to set the variable with enough scope to be available for the post run tagging.

How can you set a variable in a task that is agent scoped and can be used as the version control tag?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set version tag as an environment variable in powershell task.

```
$VERSION_TAG = {parsed value}
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VERSION_TAG]$VERSION_TAG"
```